# Execute a function on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the script below which works well, i.e. it generates a chart on the screen when the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAjax);

    function drawChartAjax() {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'json_data.aspx', 
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(data) { 
                drawChart(data); 
            } 
        });
    }

    function drawChart(json) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'did');
        data.addColumn('number', '09/10'); 

        data.addRows(json.length);  

        var l = json.length, i, x = 0, y = 0; 
        for(i = 0; i < l; i++) { 
            data.setValue(y, x, json[i].did); x++; 
            data.setValue(y, x, json[i].v1); x=0; 
            y++; 
        } 

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart( document.getElementById('chart_div') );
        chart.draw(data, {width: 300, height: 400, legend: 'bottom', title: 'title goes here'});
    }
</script>
```

What do I have to do to get this to load when a link is clicked?

I know I can display an alert like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.display_chart").click(function(event){
        alert("display the chart");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**latest answer**.

after searching what `.setOnLoadCallback()` does,

It turned out you just have to call the function on click

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.display_chart").click(function(event){
        drawChartAjax();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

---

**previous answer**.

move `google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAjax);` inside your `click` event.

like this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.display_chart").click(function(event){
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAjax); // this line should not appear anymore there at the top
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAjax);

    function drawChartAjax() {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'json_data.aspx', 
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(data) { 
                drawChart(data); 
            } 
        });
    }

    function drawChart(json) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'did');
        data.addColumn('number', '09/10'); 

        data.addRows(json.length);  

        var l = json.length, i, x = 0, y = 0; 
        for(i = 0; i < l; i++) { 
            data.setValue(y, x, json[i].did); x++; 
            data.setValue(y, x, json[i].v1); x=0; 
            y++; 
        } 

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart( document.getElementById('chart_div') );
        chart.draw(data, {width: 300, height: 400, legend: 'bottom', title: 'title goes here'});
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a.display_chart").click(function(event){
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAjax); // this line should not appear anymore there at the top
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That does not seem to work.  It stops the chart generating on page load, but when the link is clicked, nothing seems to happen, i.e. the chart does not display.

Comment: try moving also `google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});` on the `click` event

Comment: shouldn't you just call drawChartAjax() in the click event handler?

Comment: @Dror - I'm not really sure. ;) I'm not really familiar with google, I don't know what `.setOnLoadCallback()` does, I'm lazy to search for it. But that two line codes of google started the trigger, so just have to move it on the `click` event.

Comment: @Dror, @oshirowanen, see latest answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just call drawChartAjax() where you in your example calls the alert?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting just the function call in the onclick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.display_chart").click(function(event){
        drawChartAjax();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("a.display_chart").click(function(e){
        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAjax);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

function drawChartAjax() {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'json_data.aspx', 
            type: 'POST', 
            dataType: 'json', 
            success: function(data) { 
                drawChart(data); 
            } 
        });
    }

    function drawChart(json) {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'did');
        data.addColumn('number', '09/10'); 

        data.addRows(json.length);  

        var l = json.length, i, x = 0, y = 0; 
        for(i = 0; i < l; i++) { 
            data.setValue(y, x, json[i].did); x++; 
            data.setValue(y, x, json[i].v1); x=0; 
            y++; 
        } 

        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart( document.getElementById('chart_div') );
        chart.draw(data, {width: 300, height: 400, legend: 'bottom', title: 'title goes here'});
    }
```